# How to provide developer and signing information for Delphi 10.4 Sydney Android app? There are no relevant project options. Option Set must be used?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using (trying to use) Delphi 10.4 Sydney for Android app development.

I have heard and I see that Android app shold contain the information about developer. E.g. my Android devices gives the warning:

```
Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.
```

when I try to install app from uploaded APK package. I have not paid any attention to such feature and now I see that it may be important to provide information about developer. Where can I do this? I can not find Project options for that.

Similarly, when I try to install my APK I receive the error message:

```
Android existing application with the same name but conflicting signature
```

Again, I am taking over this project from previous developers and I checked the project folder, the project files - there are no keys, there are no options to provide keys.

Similarly, when I am doing 'Analyzie APK...' from Android Studio (I installed it along Delphi 10.4 specifically for viewing the APK content) I can see that MET-INF.MANIFEST.MF is using `SHA-256-Digest` for my build of APK package, but this value was `SHA1-Digest` in the previous builds, that were made with the same Delphi 10.4 installation (and Windows profile). Again, I have changed nothing in my projects options, but there is this difference.

So - my question is - how can I provide the extra information about *1) developer; 2) Andoid App signature keys; 3) the hashing algorithm used for the resources* for my Delphi 10.4 Sydney Android project? I can not fine relevant project options, relevant options in SDK manager, etc. Where these settings/options are stores and how to check/update them?

I am asking about multiple items here, but all of these seems to be connected and stored in one place, that is why my question can really be one question and not the multiple quesions in one question that are forbidden in SO.

My question is about Delphi 10.4 Syndey, but answers about Delphi 10.2 or 11.0 can be appreciated as well as they be directly lead to the answer for 10.4 edition.

***Question extended 1***: I am developing custom application, that is distributed by the simple upload, not by the GooglePlay Store. But I guess - the process for providing the developer and signature data is the same, only GooglePlay applications can have some constraints on the values of the provided devloper information and signatures.

***Question extended 2***: @mino suggested checking the 'Project - Options - Deployment - Provisioning' in his response. Indeed, this options contains 'Apply...' command with which the Option Set file can be provided. Maybe Delphi IDE does not suggest any mechanism for developer and signature information and all such information can be provided freely (along with lot of other information) with Option Set files? Maybe Delphi does not guide the developers about this kind of information? In such a case my question can be reformulated as **what is the standard format and informational content for the Option Set file(s) which are used to assign developer and signature information to the project Delphi Android Project? Is there some guidelines or Delphi documentation for this?** Maybe the developer information and signature information is target dependent and that is why it is provided for each target separately as Option Set files. Unfortunately Delphi Mobile documentation does not contain any suggestion https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Mobile_Tutorials:_Mobile_Application_Development_(iOS_and_Android)

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at "Project \ Options \ Deployment \ Provisioning"? then you have to select the version for the store.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Now I am leaning towards the idea, that this information should be provided using Option Set files in which case the guidelines about the format and content of such files would be highly useful. I extended my question taking into account this perspective.

Comment: You should read the documentation for [Project options\Deployment\Provisioning](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Provisioning_Page#Android_-_Application_Store) and follow the links for Creating a `keystone file` since from this file Delphi then reads the needed information about developer, digital signatures, etc. so that such information can be properly built into APK file so that it can be submitted to the app store.

Comment: I did create a keystone file and reinstalled Windows and installed Delphi 11.1 and used the same keystone file but I have received and error when deploying the app as a different app with the same name exist. Do you guys have any idea what should i do when I need to change computer and the app already installed on many devices that cannot be uninstalled and installed again.

Comment: Have you tried to change the name on the "Version info" page?